# Attach a custom object to a request in aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp to send and receive responses, so to record certain logs, I need to send a custom object alongwith `request` to the `on_response_prepare` method of aiohttp, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Server request is a dict-like object, you can do `request['my_key'] = custom_object`.

Please pay attention to [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please).

Comment: Point taken. It's very useful. Thanks.